# api similar to AlarmManager in android for blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager

I need to shcedule a service to run in blackberry every 60 min. In android I will use alarm manager, is there any similar api available for blackberry.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[net.rim.device.api.system.ApplicationManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/ApplicationManager.html)

Look in the API documentation under "Schedule an application to run later".

Comment: but I am actually looking for some kind of services, I want run some service classes once a day. using a scheuler. I dont want to run a application, ????????

Comment: On BlackBerry a service is simply an application without a user interface. It must extend the Application class.